# Cannot run Kafka on mac

Tags: apache-kafka

I am very new to using Microservices and having trouble running Kafka after I have started zookeeper.

Zookeeper starts fine but when I try to start my Kafka server it throws an error.

I have searched on google to try and solve my problem but its quite overwhelming, as I am not sure what all these different config files mean/do.

I have tried by enabling listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092 in server settings but it doesn't work.

I have also tried to un and reinstalled Kafka and ZooKeeper but I still get the same error.

```html
Antonias-MacBook-Pro:kafka antonia$ kafka-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties
[2020-02-25 10:26:55,944] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,514] INFO Registered signal handlers for TERM, INT, HUP (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,514] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,515] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on localhost:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,541] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Initializing a new session to localhost:2181. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,571] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.5.6-c11b7e26bc554b8523dc929761dd28808913f091, built on 10/08/2019 20:18 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,571] INFO Client environment:host.name=10.111.180.36 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,571] INFO Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_242 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,571] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=AdoptOpenJDK (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,571] INFO Client environment:java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,571] INFO Client environment:java.class.path=/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/activation-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/connect-api-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/connect-basic-auth-extension-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/connect-file-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/connect-json-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-client-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/connect-transforms-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/guava-20.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-module-paranamer-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-module-scala_2.12-2.10.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jakarta.inject-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.5.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/javassist-3.22.0-CR2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-client-2.28.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.28.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.28.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.28.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-hk2-2.28.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-media-jaxb-2.28.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.28.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-client-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-http-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-io-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-security-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-server-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-util-9.4.20.v20190813.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka-clients-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-scala_2.12-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-test-utils-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka-tools-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-2.4.0-sources.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-2.4.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/lz4-java-1.6.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/maven-artifact-3.6.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/netty-buffer-4.1.42.Final.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/netty-codec-4.1.42.Final.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/netty-common-4.1.42.Final.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/netty-handler-4.1.42.Final.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/netty-resolver-4.1.42.Final.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/netty-transport-4.1.42.Final.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.42.Final.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.42.Final.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/paranamer-2.8.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/plexus-utils-3.2.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/reflections-0.9.11.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni-5.18.3.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/scala-collection-compat_2.12-2.1.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/scala-java8-compat_2.12-0.9.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/scala-library-2.12.10.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/scala-logging_2.12-3.9.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/scala-reflect-2.12.10.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.28.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/snappy-java-1.1.7.3.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.5.6.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/zookeeper-jute-3.5.6.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.4.0/libexec/bin/../libs/zstd-jni-1.4.3-1.jar (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,572] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/Users/antonia/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:. (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,572] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/13/gvhn5dqj4179ynmpm6pkp9kh0000gn/T/ (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,572] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,572] INFO Client environment:os.name=Mac OS X (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,572] INFO Client environment:os.arch=x86_64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,573] INFO Client environment:os.version=10.14.5 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,573] INFO Client environment:user.name=antonia (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,573] INFO Client environment:user.home=/Users/antonia (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,573] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/usr/local/etc/kafka (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,573] INFO Client environment:os.memory.free=977MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,573] INFO Client environment:os.memory.max=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,573] INFO Client environment:os.memory.total=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,575] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=6000 watcher=kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$ZooKeeperClientWatcher$@28eaa59a (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,582] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,592] INFO jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,599] INFO zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled= (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,601] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,605] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,625] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:63152, server: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,641] INFO Session establishment complete on server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, sessionid = 0x10004969600000a, negotiated timeout = 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,645] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,979] INFO Cluster ID = S4SZ31nVRTCQ4uwRJ9_7mg (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,992] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.common.InconsistentClusterIdException: The Cluster ID S4SZ31nVRTCQ4uwRJ9_7mg doesn't match stored clusterId Some(Y_mQi4q4TSuhlWdx4DHiaQ) in meta.properties. The broker is trying to join the wrong cluster. Configured zookeeper.connect may be wrong.
 at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:220)
 at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
 at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:84)
 at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,995] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-02-25 10:26:56,997] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-02-25 10:26:57,109] INFO Session: 0x10004969600000a closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-02-25 10:26:57,109] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x10004969600000a (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-02-25 10:26:57,111] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-02-25 10:26:57,118] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-02-25 10:26:57,119] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[2020-02-25 10:26:57,120] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Comment: Share your `server.properties` and `zookeeper.properties` files

Comment: broker.id=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/usr/local/var/lib/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0

Comment: delete.topic.enable=true

This is for server.properties

Comment: Edit your question.

Comment: dataDir=/usr/local/var/lib/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
maxClientCnxns=0
admin.enableServer=false

zookeeper.properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the problem is shown in this message:

> kafka.common.InconsistentClusterIdException:
>
> The Cluster ID S4SZ31nVRTCQ4uwRJ9_7mg
>
> doesn't match stored clusterId Some(Y_mQi4q4TSuhlWdx4DHiaQ)
>
> in meta.properties.
>
> The broker is trying to join the wrong cluster.
> Configured zookeeper.connect may be wrong.

The above problem occurs when a new instance of Kafka is being started up on data storage created by another kafka server. Kafka stores its messages in 'log' files.

**How to fix the problem?**

The problem can be fixed in these steps:

1. Shutdown both Kafka and Zookeeper
2. If required, take backup of the existing logs of Kafka and Zookeeper
3. Delete the log directories of both Kafka and Zookeeper
4. Restart Zookeeper and Kafka